# Limit number of mongodb insertions

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nosql

Is there a way to set a fixed limit on the number of documents that can be inserted via a bulk insert in `mongodb` using the `node.js` client?

I am inserting a number of documents into a collection that has a unique index on `fieldA` via a bulk insert. Some of the inserts will fail due to `fieldA` being non-unique, so I can't know how many will be inserted beforehand, but I want to limit the `nInserted` so that the total of these documents never goes over 5000.

All I can think to do is to run the full insert and if `nInserted` brings the total above 5000 I remove the `n` last inserted documents such that the total is 5000 but this seems a bit silly.

The ordered bulk insert is almost right but I don't want it to stop on the first index conflict but keep going if there is still room (ie < 5000 total).

Here's an example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
db.myCol.count({foo: val}, function(err, count) {
    var remaining = 5000 - count;
    if (remaining > 0) {
        var bulk = db.myCol.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
        toInsert.forEach(function(item) {
            bulk.insert(item);
        });

        // make sure no more than remaining is inserted
        bulk.execute(function(err, result) {
            // currently, I would just insert all and
            // then remove the overflow with another db action
            // if nInserted + count > 5000
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: So, you want to have 5000 records in the collection once the bulk operation is complete? Can you post the implementation you have tried?

Comment: @BatScream I want to make sure no more than 5000 of a particular type of document is > 5000 after I run the bulk insert. I have updated the question to give an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no way to tell the `Bulk` API to stop inserting any records once the limit of successful inserts has been reached. 
One way of doing it in the client side,

- Feed the `Bulk` API at most `n`(5000 in this case) documents at a
  time
- If any error has occurred during the insert, Bulk insert the
  remaining.
- Do it recursively.
- You can further add logic to process only remaining number of
  records if `remaining < max`.

Modified code:

```
var toInsert = [..];  // documents to be inserted.

var max = 5000;  // max records for Bulk insert.

function execBulk(start,end){
    db.myCol.count({foo: 'bar'}, function(err, count) {
    var remaining = total - count;
    if (remaining > 0 && toInsert.length > start) {
        var bulk = db.myCol.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
        toInsert.slice(start,end).forEach(function(item) {
            bulk.insert(item);
        });
        // insert the records
        bulk.execute(function(err, result) {
            if(err){
              console.log(err);
              // insert next set of at most 5000 records.
              execBulk(end,end+max-1)
            }
            else
            {
                console.log(results);
            }
        });
    }
});
}
```

Invoking the function:

```
execBulk(0,max);
```